# How to get multiple rows by ID sql query?

Tags: sql

example:

```
ID|Name|Date|
-------------
1 |john|7/19|
2 |Bob |7/19|
3 |Burt|7/19|
```

Let's say I want to grab all rows where ID= 1 && 2.

How would I do so?

Comment: `where ID = 1 or ID = 2`

Comment: so the or acts as an && and grabs both?

also am I able to do something along the lines of:
       where ID = 1 or ID = 2 or ID = 3?
 @Marwelln

Comment: You can also use the `IN` operator. `where ID IN(1, 2)`

Comment: @StarScream: *"so the or acts as an &&"* - Nope, it acts as an `or`.  There is no record where `ID = 1` **and** `ID = 2`.  The `WHERE` clause is just looking for an expression which resolves to a boolean value.  That expression can be as large and complex as you like, composed of many different smaller expressions which each resolve to boolean values.  But the whole thing needs to resolve to a boolean value.  Any record for which the expression resolves to `true` is returned in the results, any record for which the expression resolves to `false` is not returned.

Comment: `the or acts as an &&`...no, it acts as an `OR` and finds all rows where the ID is 1 or the ID is 2. The ID cannot be 1 **and** 2 in the same row, so && or AND cannot work. Remember that the WHERE clause in SQL is applied to each row in turn, individually. Rows which meet the criteria are included in the query, all others are excluded.

Comment: p.s. this has nothing to do with PHP, so I removed the tag.

Comment: The tag [php] was removed (and that's good), because the output of the PHP code `print 1&&2;` is `1`.  (see: [logical operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Let's say I want to grab all rows where ID= 1 && 2

Don't think of it in terms of human language.  Think of it in terms of boolean logic.  Expressions which resolve to true/false values, which can be combined using boolean operators to resolve to true/false values.

A logical "and" won't work because there is no record for which `ID=1` **and** `ID=2`.  You could write that query, it would just always return no results.

What you want is any record where `ID=1` **or** `ID=2`.  For two of the records shown, one of those expressions will resolve to `true` and one to `false`.  And `true or false` resolves to `true`.

You can combine and expand the `WHERE` expression all you like, as long as it still resolves to a single boolean value.  Records for which that value is `true` will be returned, records for which it is `false` will not.

In that example you have two expressions, combined with an `or` to create a larger expression:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID=1 OR ID=2
```

To help illustrate, you can use explicit parentheses to group expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ((ID=1) OR (ID=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the syntax,

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 ...;

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany' AND City='Berlin';
```